# Override first/last name splitting for one entry in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, formatting

I want to preserve the ordering of the author field and avoid the automatic abbreviations, and only that, for this specific entry.

I have something like:

```
@TECHREPORT{abcd2012,
  author = {Free Software Foundation},
  title = {Some study},
  year = {2012}
}
```

By default, it displays the author name as:

> FOUNDATION, F. S.

and when I use `\citeauthoronline`: Foundation

I want it to display:

> FREE SOFTWARE FOUNDATION

And for when I use `\citeauthoronline`:

> Free Software Foundation

If I add an additional pair of `{}`, it prevents splitting, but also blocks further desired formatting from the bibliography style (capitalization). So, this solution isn't acceptable.

What I can do to achieve the desired effect?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention my bibliography style, ABNTeX:

```
\usepackage[alf,abnt-etal-text=emph]{abntcite}
```

Comment: Does either `author = {Free~Software~Foundation}` or `author = {FREE~SOFTWARE~FOUNDATION}` work for your case?

Comment: Would you please add the bib style you're using? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be very useful. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: The `~` works the same as the simple space here. It doesn't solve the problem. I'm using the ABNTeX style, but I guess that Jellby answer works for all styles.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Does this work as you want?

```
@TECHREPORT{abcd2012,
  author = {Free{\ }Software{\ }Foundation},
  title = {Some study},
  year = {2012}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

This isn't directly a answer to what I asked, like Jellby's was, but a way to avoid this problem altogether by doing the right thing with my style:

```
@TECHREPORT{abcd2012,
  organization = {Free Software Foundation},
  title = {Some study},
  year = {2012}
}
```

I found that changing `author = {}` to `organization = {}` results in the output I expected. The downside is that JabRef doesn't offer this option, only `institution = {}`, that don't works in this way with my style. That's also why I haven't discovered it sooner... So I need to manually edit the BibTeX entry, and the author field in JabRef remains empty... but still, I think it is less hackish.

I can also use `org-short = {FSF}` in order to define a shorter name for citations on the middle of the text, but this goes beyond my original question.

Comment: This shows a good reason why a minimal example should *always* be included in this type of questions: it's impossible to guess the bibliography style and its interactions with the document class.

Comment: Yeah... I thought that only the bibliographic entry and it's output was sufficient, but I forgot how diverse the bibliographic styles were...