# Cite R using BibTex

Tags: bibtex, endnotes

I would like to cite R (statisticak package) using BibTex.
The author's name should be 'R Development Core Team', but it recognize 'R Development Core' as a first name and 'Team' as a last name so it appears as 'Team, R. D. C' in the final output PDF file.

There is a tip for solving this problem.
http://rtutorialseries.blogspot.com/2012/01/r-tutorial-series-citing-r-with-endnote.html#comment-form
This blog suggests to put a comma after 'R Development Core Team', so that BibTex recognize 'R Development Core Team' as a last name and there is no first name.
But this tip does not work for me. I'm using EndNote X7 for Mac to create the BibTex file and BibDesk to edit the bibtex file.
The author's name still appears as 'Team, R. D. C.'.

Comment: Try to put the whole name in braces. Or try that question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60141/override-first-last-name-splitting-for-one-entry-in-bibtex

Comment: Enter in R and write `citation()` to obtain the right BibTeX entry. Note that the field author is `{{R Core Team}}`as Astrinus suggest.

Comment: When I entered author name as 'R{\ }Core{\ }Team,' in Endnote, it worked.